# Stubbed function doesn't return correct value when called by another function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I have function A, which gets a value from function B and compares it to a string. If they match it returns true, else it returns false.

```
function A(random) {
    var something = B();
    if (random === something) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function B() {
    var something = 'hello';

    return something;
}
```

My test looks like this

```
test("Test ", function () {
    //Arrange
    var expected = true;
    var random = "hi";
    var B = sinon.stub();
    B.returns(random);

    //Act
    var actual = A('hi'); 

    //Assert
    deepEqual(actual, expected);
});
```

I have successfully stubbed out function B to return a value of my choice using Sinon. When I call function B directly in a test it returns the stubbed value, however when I call function A it no longer returns the stubbed value, any idea why?

Comment: Need more information. Show what result you call A with and what B returns. A expects B to return a value (probably object) that has a type property, so first guess would be that B no longer returns an object after stubbing it.

Comment: Can you provide more info like .If the stubbed function is using `this` etc

Comment: You're comparing `something.type` to `result`, have you checked what value `something.type` actually has?

Comment: The syntax works perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/0aw5jh3q/ ... There must be something with your `B` function that is not returning the right "stuff".

Comment: You are aware of the typo in function A? `random === somthing` there is an  `e` missing in `somthing`

Comment: Thanks @Jordumus,  but the name changes were done just for posting purposes, so still have the problem

Comment: You're not actually stubbing `B`, you're creating a new local variable with the same name.

Comment: @robertklep Would you mind giving me an idea of how to actually stub it? I am new to javascript and unit testing

Answer (score 1):

You are not really stubbing `A` or `B` functions, just creating a new local one with the same name.

If you want to inject(replace) the function the function, you have to refactor your code in a more test-driven way (i.e using objects, without local functions, [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)...).

Or use tools like [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to modify local module-scope variables and inject the stubbed/fake ones.

i.e.

```
// same as require, but create a new copy (not cached)
// with  __set__ and __get__ methods:

var myModule = rewire('./myModule')
  , stubbedB = sinon.stub();

myModule.__set__("B", stubbedB);
myModule.__get__("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few refactor so that you don't need any additional package like `rewire`.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
function A(random) {
  const something = exports.B();
  if (random === something) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function B() {
  const something = 'hello';

  return something;
}

exports.A = A;
exports.B = B;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const mod = require('./');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('39266915', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should return true', () => {
    sinon.stub(mod, 'B').returns('hi');
    const actual = mod.A('hi');
    expect(actual).to.be.true;
  });

  it('should return false', () => {
    sinon.stub(mod, 'B').returns('hello');
    const actual = mod.A('hi');
    expect(actual).to.be.false;
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  39266915
    ✓ should return true
    ✓ should return false


  2 passing (9ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |      100 |      50 |      75 |                   
 index.js |      75 |      100 |      50 |      75 | 11,13             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/39266915